# Backbone boilerplate router's root for offline and pre-production

Tags: javascript, html, model-view-controller, backbone.js

I am using the backbone boilerplate here
https://github.com/tbranyen/backbone-boilerplate

I do development in static html/js offline and do test offline before uploading to another **pre-production** site online. What annoyed me is that the router works in **pre-production** but not offline. This is the `root` for pre:

```
  var app = {
    // The root path to run the application.
    root: "/myfolder/"
  };
```

This is the URL for online **pre-production**:

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/myfolder/index.html
```

This is URL for offline:

```
file:///C:/Users/MyHome/Desktop/MyProject/MyApp/index.html
```

What do I use for `root` in offline? Is there a way NOT to keep changing `root` every time I upload to pre-production? Or does router not working in static html at all?

p.s. This is the code in **main.js**

```
Backbone.history.start({ pushState: true, root: app.root });
```

Comment: You test your website off the `file` protocol? You should at least test on a local server. There are subtle differences between them.

Comment: yah b/c it's just html and js so no need for anything fancy. I just need the pushState to work. Does it work offline on file protocol in a browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind. After doing some reading, pushState does not work with file protocol

https://github.com/mtrpcic/pathjs

http://html5doctor.com/history-api/

The HTML5 Mozilla document doesn't say this though.